# I want to add an Incremental number to an existing CSV Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Being new to Powershell I managed to get together a script.
This already prepares a csv where I know, a preview of the file below:

```
"Documentnummer","Versie","Status","Geocode","IDS datum","Documentgroep (Omsch)","Documenttype (Wrd)","Tekeningnummer"
"550165","C","AB","008","19.07.2013","Themalagen OI","KS","008KS10"
 "550164","I","AB","008","26.03.2016","Themalagen OI","KS","008KS09"
 "550163","D","AB","008","19.07.2013","Themalagen OI","KS","008KS08"
```

This goes on for about 2000 lines.
Now, I use this to download files, and when downloaded I create the file name using the same csv.
Here is the question, I want to create and extra column, header e.g. 'Nummer' that contains an increasing number for each row;

```
Nummer 0001, 0002, 0003, ...., 0050, ...., 0105, ...., 2547
```

I always want four digits so it looks like this:

```
"Nummer","Documentnummer","Versie","Status","Geocode","IDS datum","Documentgroep (Omsch)","Documenttype (Wrd)","Tekeningnummer"
"0001","550165","C","AB","008","19.07.2013","Themalagen OI","KS","008KS10"
"0002","550164","I","AB","008","26.03.2016","Themalagen OI","KS","008KS09"
...
"0108","550163","D","AB","008","19.07.2013","Themalagen OI","KS","008KS08"
```

I tried it two ways and both failed, creating an incremental number an adding it to the csv and creating a csv with the right numbers, and merging both csv's.

Help is appreciated!
(And sorry for the dutch header names)

Using Powershell 3.0 on Windows 7 x64

Update, the code I used to merge the two files:

```
$drawinfo = Import-Csv $downloads\${drawtype}_DIR_AUTO_FILTER.csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
$numberinfo = Import-Csv "$BBKSDIR\Related files\Incremental_number.csv" | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The first one contains the bulk data, the second one only holds the numbers.

```
[array]$allinfo = "{0},{1}" -f $numberinfo[0],$drawinfo[0]
[array]$allinfo += "`r`n{0},{1}" -f $numberinfo[1],$drawinfo[1]
$allinfo
```

Here I first get the header row of both files, and in the second row I want to get all the other rows, but I'm only getting the 2nd row (1st data row).

Executing $allinfo now gets me:

> "Nummer","Documentnummer","Versie","Status","Geocode","IDS datum","Documentgroep (Omsch)","Documenttype (Wrd)","Tekeningnummer"
>   "0001","550165","C","AB","008","19.07.2013","Themalagen OI","KS","008KS10"

Comment: Can you share the code of whatever you have tried till now?

Comment: As you can see in the update, Im kind of close (or I want to be O:) ).
The number is added as a first column, and the first data row is exactly how I want it to be, the first column with the number in four digits, but that should go on for all the other rows.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should give you a hint about how to do it:

```
 $csv = Import-Csv "D:\temp\test.csv"
 $global:i = 0; $csv | Select-Object @{ Name = 'Nummer'; Expression = { $global:i.ToString("0000"); $global:i += 1 } }, * | Export-Csv "D:\temp\test2.csv"
```

This is based on calculated properties.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had assumed it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$script:cpt=0
import-csv "C:\temp10\report.csv" | 
            select @{N="Nummer";E={$script:cpt++;"{0:d4}" -f $script:cpt}}, * | 
                        export-csv "C:\temp10\report2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: And what is the difference with the response bellow?

Comment: not really difference, dont offence you,  just an other method,  format nummer and use $script vs $global, ++ is better of += in performance, i prefert -format for better visibility,  but -NoTypeInformation is important (you have forget that)